# call to undefined function phperror_reporting() on index.php

Tags: php

my opencart website suddenly stopped working and showing blank page, when i checked error log it shows following

[22-Nov-2016 10:20:26 Etc/GMT] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function phperror_reporting() in /home/haroosig/public_html/kashmirkit.com/index.php on line 1

but i dont see any phperror_reporting() in index.php as:

```
<?php
// Version
define('VERSION', '2.2.0.0');

// Configuration
if (is_file('config.php')) {
    require_once('config.php');
}

// Install
if (!defined('DIR_APPLICATION')) {
    header('Location: install/index.php');
    exit;
}

// VirtualQMOD
require_once('./vqmod/vqmod.php');
VQMod::bootup();

// VQMODDED Startup
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php'));

$application_config = 'catalog';

// Application
require_once(VQMod::modCheck(DIR_SYSTEM . 'framework.php'));
```

please help

Comment: look for `<?phperror_reporting()`, somewhere in them included files.

Comment: where to look, i dont understand

Comment: `kashmirkit.com` in `public_html` folder looks suspicious, because it is usually domain root itsef (code injection?). Do you recognise that folder? Did you looked for `index.php` inside this one?

Comment: but it was same as before and it worked fine... how can i check it?

Comment: well well, i resolved this whole mess....
there is no error in index.php, actually it was in the file i was editing, and error log was somehow showing error in index.php